# doing an assignment in python for computer science and my for loop repeats sections more then once

Tags: python

This is a code for my computer science class, I'm making a guessing game where you have to guess cities and I'm gonna have a long list of cities with hints, however when i play it now it repeats the same city twice occasionally when its only supposed to run 5 of the cities sections of code. I know that the more cities it has the less it likely it is that the will repeat but I'm only gonna have around 20 cities so id like to know how to stop it from repeating a city twice. Ps: i don't know how to use this website so i don't know if i asked this question correctly i think the indentation got all messed up too bye.

Code:

```
import random
for counter in range(0,5):
Cities = random.randint (1,9)

if Cities == 1:
print("This city is the fourth largest city in South Korea")
City1="Daegu"
guess1= input() 
if guess1!=City1:
    print("The City you are looking for is the birthplace of Leo Hong")
    guess1=input()
if guess1!=City1:
    print("Alright this is your last guess, this city begins with a D")
    guess1=input()
if guess1!=City1:
    print("You lose how could you not guess that")
    exit() 
if guess1==City1:
    print("Congrats worthless player you got this city, the next one is difficult see if you can get it")

if Cities == 2:
    print("This city is a small farm filled town north of Burlington and Waterdown")
    City2="Carlisle"
    guess2= input()
    if guess2!=City2:
        print("The City you are looking for is where Connor lives")
        guess2=input()
    if guess2!=City2:
        print("Alright this is your last guess, this city begins with a C")
        guess2=input()
    if guess2!=City2:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once")
        exit()
    if guess2==City2:
        print("Wow worthless player aren't you smart you got this city, we'll see if you can get this next city")

if Cities == 3:
    print("This city is the largest city in Afghanistan")
    City3="Kabul"
    guess3= input()
    if guess3!=City3:
        print("This city is کا‌‌‌بل")
        guess3=input()
    if guess3!=City3:
        print("Alright this is your last guess, this city begins with a K")
        guess3=input()
    if guess3!=City3:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess3==City3:
        print("amazing worthless player you're smart, we'll see if you can get this next city")

if Cities == 4:
    print("This city is a tiny town in Texas with a sick name")
    City4="Happy"
    guess4= input()
    if guess4!=City4:
        print("Their motto is, A town without a frown")
        guess4=input()
    if guess4!=City4:
        print("Alright this is your last guess, this town is named after a mood")
        guess4=input()
    if guess4!=City4:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess4==City4:
        print("great worthless player you're genius like Neil, we'll see if you can get the next city")

if Cities == 5:
    print("now this city is a small town in Iowa with a physics related name")
    City5="Gravity"
    guess5= input()
    if guess5!=City5:
        print("Their motto is were down to earth")
        guess5=input()
    if guess5!=City5:
        print("Your last hint is 9.81")
        guess5=input()
    if guess5!=City5:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess5==City5:
        print("great worthless player youve completed the city Gravity, lets see whats next")

if Cities == 6:
    print("This city is a large city in somalia")
    City6="Mogadishu"
    guess6= input()
    if guess6!=City6:
        print("It is the setting of Black Hawk Down")
        guess5=input()
    if guess6!=City6:
        print("It is on the coast of somalia")
        guess6=input()
    if guess6!=City6:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess6==City6:
        print("great worthless player youve got Mogadishu lets see whats next")

if Cities == 7:
    print("This city is a large city in Mongolia")
    City7="Ulaanbaatar"
    guess7= input()
    if guess7!=City7:
        print("It is an independant municipality")
        guess7=input()
    if guess7!=City7:
        print("It is the capital of Mongolia")
        guess7=input()
    if guess7!=City7:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess7==City7:
        print("great worthless player youve got Ulaanbaatar lets see whats next")

if Cities == 8:
    print("This one is a small community in Arkansas, USA")
    City8="Toadsuck"
    guess8= input()
    if guess8!=City8:
        print("this close relative of the frog sucks")
        guess8=input()
    if guess8!=City8:
        print("The answer is ____suck where the blank is the relative of the frog")
        guess8=input()
    if guess8!=City8:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess8==City8:
        print("lmao that one was funny great worthless player youve got Toadsuck lets see whats next")

if Cities == 9:
    print("This one is a village in Connecticut")
    City9="Gaylordsville"
    guess9= input()
    if guess9!=City9:
        print("this is the ville of the main character in Meet the Fockers")
        guess9=input()
    if guess9!=City9:
        print("in Litchfield county")
        guess9=input()
    if guess9!=City9:
        print("You lose get out of my sight at once filthy pleb")
        exit()
    if guess9==City9:
        print("good for you worthless player youve got Gaylordsville, lets see whats next")
```

Comment: Here's a hint for refactoring: one of the guiding principles of Python is DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself. Take a good look at your code and think about all the repetition, and how long it took you to write out what you have. What if the requirement now changes to 100 cities? Encapsulate your logic in functions that can be called multiple times. Look at dictionaries as data structures.

Comment: those LMGTFY comments were out of line, and I apologize to you on behalf of the community here. Most people here genuinely want to help, but there **are** some barriers to entry. Please read through the [help] to learn more about Stack Overflow, especially the section on [ask]. Python is a wonderful language, and if you stick with it you can do some pretty cool things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that at each iteration you're using `random.randint` to get your next guess. Rather than using that, try this:

```
for city in random.sample(range(NUM_CITIES), NUM_ROUNDS):
    ...
```

This will choose a random `NUM_ROUNDS` values from `range(NUM_CITIES)`. Note that this allows `city` to be 0 up to `NUM_CITIES - 1` rather than 1 to `NUM_CITIES`. You can use `range(1, NUM_CITIES+1)` if you really want it to start with 1, but I'd suggest you get used to starting with zero as that is standard in programming.

Comment: thank you very much sir i was able to incorporate it into the code and it hasn't repeated since. True boo